# Como percorrer uma classe C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho a `DeserializeObject` que preenche uma classe de pedido e itens, nos itens que preciso percorrer esta classe para gravar os dados, da forma que estou fazendo está zerando o registros, como eu poderia ler os dados?.

```
public class Item
{
    public string idItemPedido { get; set; }
    public int item { get; set; }
    public string plano { get; set; }
    public Produto produto { get; set; }
    public string descricaoItem { get; set; }
    public decimal valorUnitario { get; set; }
    public string qtde { get; set; }
    public decimal valorTotal { get; set; }
    public string pontos { get; set; }
}

   string teste = "115873";
   GravaItensPedido(teste);


   public void GravaItensPedido(string CodigoCabecahoPedido)
        {
            var strQuery = "";
            IEnumerable<Item> enumeracao = new List<Item>();

            foreach (var item in enumeracao)
            {
                strQuery = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Consultar dados de uma coleção na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262920/consultar-dados-de-uma-cole%c3%a7%c3%a3o-na-mem%c3%b3ria)

Answer (score 0):

Você quer gerar uma query de update/insert para as propriedades da classe?

Se for isso, recomendo usar Dapper pra te ajudar.
É uma biblioteca C# criada pelo time do StackOverflow.

Vai te ajudar muito: [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Olha que legal:

```cs
var count = connection.Execute(@"
  set nocount on 
  create table #t(i int) 
  set nocount off 
  insert #t 
  select @a a union all select @b 
  set nocount on 
  drop table #t", new {a=1, b=2 });
Assert.Equal(2, count);
```

Você pega uma conexão ADO.NET, vai ter um método de extensão chamado *Execute*.
Daí vc chama ele com 2 parâmetros.

- no 1 parâmetro você passa a sql
- no 2o parâmetro você passa um objeto, com os dados pra ele montar a query pra vc.

Que tal?

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda mais não e isso, como falei na minha pergunta, a classe já está preenchida com os dados que veio do Json, por isso falei que tinha feito o DeserializeObject , o que preciso e percorrer os registros que estão nesta classe.

Comment: Você acessar as propriedades dela, sem ter que referenciar diretamente uma-a-uma?

Se for isso, você pode usar reflection. Conhece?

Comment: Gabriel, veja ser ficou mais claro :https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262920/ienumerable-%C3%A9-o-melhor-para-consultar-dados-de-cole%C3%A7%C3%B5es-na-mem%C3%B3ria

Answer (score 0):

Tem algo faltando na sua pergunta, entao

caso 1 : voce informa o parametro(codigoCabecahoPedido) e recebe uma lista
usando algum metodo

```
public void GravaItensPedido(string codigoCabecahoPedido)
{

      List<Item> minhaLista= getlistblabla(x=>x.CodigoCabecahoPedido == codigoCabecahoPedido);

      foreach (var itens in minhaLista)
      {
         //Faz alguma coisa
      }
}
```

caso 2: voce passa a lista que vai ser alterada ou algo do tipo

```
public void GravaItensPedido(string codigoCabecahoPedido, List<Item> itens)
{      
  var strQuery = "";

  foreach (var itens in itens)
  {
      if(codigoCabecahoPedido == "test")
      {
        //faca alguma coisa
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hudson, ajustei a minha pergunta, mais não deu certo a solução, se for possível ajudar eu agradeço

Comment: tem como reformular sua pergunta? ainda nao consigo enteder o que voce realmente quer

Comment: Hudson, veja se ficou mais claro https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262920/ienumerable-%C3%A9-o-melhor-para-consultar-dados-de-cole%C3%A7%C3%B5es-na-mem%C3%B3ria

Comment: esse (string CodigoCabecahoPedido) é o seu json?